# Elementwise arithmetic operations in Kotlin

Tags: functional-programming, kotlin

What's the best way to make elementwise operations on arrays/lists of Doubles in kotlin?
I'd like to achieve something concise as

```
zip(vec1, weights1).map(*) + zip(vec2, weights2).map(*)
```

where the plus operation should add the resulting products elementwise (+ as an arithmetic addition, not a concatenation of lists)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kotlin way would be to use regular `Collection`/`Sequence` operators, which there are plenty.

In this case, if you want to do something on every corresponding (index-wise) pair of elements of two lists, you would want to use [`zip`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip.html) operator, which makes list of [`Pair`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-pair/index.html)s. You can operate on pairs pretty easy with Kotlin destructuring.

If I understood what you want to achieve correctly, your example would be represented as (I used variables just for readability sake):

```
val result1 = vec1.zip(weights1) { a, b -> a * b }
val result2 = vec2.zip(weights2) { a, b -> a * b }
result1.zip(result2).map { (a, b) -> a + b }
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, this is what I wanted to achieve. Is there any simpler/shorter way to express this, though?

Comment: With pure Kotlin, I belive there is no better way. Alternatively, you could write your own DSL (see: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html ) or list implementation and override `+` operator, see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html